# How to decide the form of verb when the subject has "of"?

Tags: verbs, verb-agreement

Specifically, I am trying to write this sentence, and I am not sure whether I should use "was" or "were" in the sentence.

The order of probability features and amount features was/were counterbalanced across subjects.

My advisor changed "was" to "were", but I don't understand why. I think the subject of this sentence is "order", but "features".

Comment: I agree with you that the subject of the sentence is "order", and therefore "was" should be the verb.

Comment: In my opinion were is more appropriate because 'order of probability features' and '(order of) amount features' are two different elements, if I understand the sentence correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're describing a psychological experiment with two variables. In this case, you can simply use the plural 'orders', because each variable has its own order. *Both...and...* makes it even clearer that there are two variables under discussion:

- The orders of both probability features and amount features were counterbalanced across subjects.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to English Language Learners!

Your advisor understood the subject of the sentence to be plural, in which case we use the third person plural form of the verb, 'were'.

The two parts of the subject in your advisor's mind are:

> The order of probability features
> The order of amount features

These two are combined to together and the word 'order' applies to both. This means that the order of the features within each set of features was counterbalanced.

If you meant for 'order' to be the only subject, a better way to write the sentence is

> The order between probability features and amount features was counterbalanced across subjects.

This means that the order of the two sets of features was counterbalanced.

Another way to say it, without 'order' as the subject is

> Probability features and amount features were ordered in a counterbalanced way across subjects.